# Cual es la utilidad real de la POO en php sobre la Estructurada?

Tags: php, poo

Tengo muchos años 6 aproximadamente programando en php siempre lo he hecho de manera Estructurada usando funciones y creando un archivo con estas mismas el cual es llamado con un include('lib.php') allí pro ejemplo tengo una función que me genera un elemento para formularios HTML ejemplo

```
    //Funcion que se encarga de generar elementos
function form($tipo,$name,$label,$placeholder,$value=null){
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="<?php echo $name;?>" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?php echo $label;?></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
        <?php switch($tipo)
            {
                case "text":
            ?>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="<?php echo $name;?>" placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder;?>" required name="<?php echo $name;?>" value="<?php echo $value;?>">
            <?php
                break;
                case "email":
            ?>
<input type="email" class="form-control @rror('email')" id="<?php echo $name;?>" placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder;?>" required name="<?php echo $name;?>" value="<?php echo $value;?>">
            <?php
                break;
                case "nota":
echo $value;
                break;
                case "clave":
                ?>
<input type="password" id="<?php echo $name;?>" class="form-control @error('password')" name="<?php echo $name;?>" required>
                <?php
                break;?>
```

donde necesito un campo tipo texto voy realizando esto

```
        form("text","nombre","Nombre","Ingrese el nombre del personal autorizado");
        form("email","correo","Correo electronico","alguien@alguien.com");
```

Ahora en que me beneficia en caso de ese ejemplo muy básico el uso de POO y como podría hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta a esta pregunta puede ser muy amplia. Se puede resumir en la descripción de las características básicas de la **POO** y las ventajas y desventajas que tiene con respecto a la **programación estructurada**.

Se pueden describir los **principios básicos de la POO** como los siguientes:

- **Encapsulamiento:** Es el mecanismo por el que se regula el acceso a los datos. Los objetos creados a partir de clases actuan como cajas negras y solo se puede acceder a los datos (atributos de los objetos) mediante métodos.
- **Herencia:** Proceso mediante el cual un objeto puede adquirir propiedades de otro objeto padre. Las clases hijas pueden tener sus propios metodos y atributos. Esto es útil para la reutilización de código.
- **Polimorfismo:** El polimorfismo se refiere a la propiedad por la que es posible enviar mensajes sintácticamente iguales a objetos de tipos distintos. El único requisito que deben cumplir los objetos que se utilizan de manera polimórfica es saber responder al mensaje que se les envía. Gracias a esto, objetos diferentes pueden ser tratados de la misma manera.
- **Abstraccion** Expresa las características esenciales de un objeto, las cuales distinguen al objeto de los demás. Además de distinguir entre los objetos provee límites conceptuales.

Aplicando los principios básicos de la POO obtenemos un conjunto de caracteristicas:

- Se **utilizan objetos**, los cuales se les pueden pedir que **realicen operaciones sobre si mismos**.
- Un programa en POO es un **conjunto de objetos comunicándose entre sí**, indicando unos a otros que hacer mediante el envío de mensajes u ordenes.
- Cada **objeto** puede estar **formado a su vez, por otros objetos**.
- Cada objeto tiene un tipo. **Un objeto es una instancia de una clase**.
- Todos los objetos de un tipo particular pueden recibir los mismos mensajes, se debe a que están creados de la misma plantilla (clase). De igual modo debido a relaciones de "herencia" un objeto podría recibir partes de su "padre".

Al **crear una clase** se debe definir un **conjunto de atributos** (datos) y también un **conjunto de métodos** ("Funciones" que se utilizarán para tratar esos datos). **Cada objeto** que se vaya a usar en el programa **será una instanciación de una clase** creada previamente (como si fuera una plantilla).

En conclusión, al aplicar todos los factores descritos, las **ventajas de la POO** pueden ser varias, pero las más importantes son las siguientes:

- **Reutilización de código**
- **Portabilidad**
- **Mantenimiento**

Con esto se obtendrá un **programa que sea más manipulable**, que a en un futuro a la hora de **agregar funcionalidades** sean más **fáciles de implementar**. Un programa más **ordenado** con una forma de codificarlo más **entendible** facilitando el hecho de  **reutilizar código** y a su vez, un programa que puede ser **útil en gran medida en otros proyectos**.

Lo más complicado de la POO es que requiere una gran **curva de aprendizaje, una nueva forma de pensar a la hora de programar**, también que cada objeto no se diseña aisladamente, depende de sus relaciones con otros objetos y por último, desarrollar una buena aplicación basada en **la POO requiere experiencia y un buen diseño**.

Comment: Ok entiendo, sin embargo me gustaria basado en mi ejemplo que ventajas tiene, ya que como te explique he usado de esa manera utilizando funciones, como puedo hacer ese ejemplo en POO?

Answer (score 1):

Hoy en día hay muchas librerías como `Blade` o `Twig` para la renderización de HTML usando `templates`, pero trataré de mostrar un ejemplo del uso de clase para tu ejemplo especifico.

Interfaz para todos los ojetos asociados al DOM Html

```
<?php

namespace Html;

interface Dom
{
    public function render(): string;
}
```

Abstracción de cualquier elemento Html

```
<?php

namespace Html;

abstract class Element implements Dom
{
    private $attributes;

    private $content;

    public function __construct(array $attributes, string $content = null)
    {
        $this->attributes = array_filter($attributes);
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    public function getAttributesAsString(): string
    {
        $attributes = '';

        array_walk($this->attributes, function ($value, $key) use (&$attributes) {
            $attributes .= is_bool($value) ? " $key" : " $key='$value'";
        });

        return $attributes;
    }

    public abstract function getTag(): string;

    public function getContent(): string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function render(): string
    {
        return "<{$this->getTag()} {$this->getAttributesAsString()}>{$this->getContent()}</{$this->getTag()}>";
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->render();
    }

}
```

Una especificación de un elemento (un control input)

```
<?php

namespace Html;

class Input extends Element
{
    public function getTag(): string
    {
        return 'input';
    }

    public function render(): string
    {
        return "<{$this->getTag()} {$this->getAttributesAsString()}/>";
    }
}
```

Una especificación de un elemento (un label)

```
<?php

namespace Html;

class Label extends Element
{

    public function getTag(): string
    {
        return 'label';
    }
}
```

Implementación

```
<?php

namespace Html;

echo new Input(['id' => 'one']);
echo new Input(['id' => 'two', 'placeholder' => 'this is two', 'required' => true]);
echo new Label(['id' => 'three'], 'a message');
```

Respuesta

```
<input  id='one'/>
<input  id='two' placeholder='this is two' required/>
<label  id='three'>a message</label>
```

De hecho no es el ejemplo mas pulido del mundo, aún podríamos llegar a armar una compleja red de interfaces que definan los diferentes tipos de elementos Html y los generalicen, sin embargo, la premisa es simple *"divide y vencerás"* una clase hace un grupo de actividades relacionado a una entidad y solo una entidad y esta a su vez podrá ser extendida permitiendo la reutilización de código. Hay otras muchas ventajas pero creo @Deivid_41 ya trato de la teoría.